# Haskell log viewer

Tags: haskell, logging, apache-chainsaw

I implemented logging in my program using [HSLogger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.2.10/docs/System-Log-Handler-Log4jXML.html).
I use [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/) to view the logs.
A first concern is that the logs are not updated in real time when I use the option "Open remote log4J File".

Other concerns is that HSLogger supports only Log4J, which seems deprecated now.
Chainsaw official version dates back to 2007.

All in all, what is the current story for logging and viewing logs in Haskell?

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I updated to make it more clear.